# jquery not finding my json value?

Tags: jquery, json

I am returning some json from my server side code.

`console.log(data)` is giving me:

```
{
   "VRM": "DG70XSC",
   "Make": "FORD",
   "Model": "FOCUS ZETEC CLIMATE 116",
   "Body": "5 DOOR HATCHBACK",
   "Doors": "5 DOORS",
   "Seats": 5,
   "BodyDescription": "hatchback"
}
```

Why in this case is console.log(data.BodyDescription) undefined?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `console.log` giving you a string or an object?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to _parse_ the JSON? Can you provide a fiddle that shows this happening?

Comment: Apologies all I was indeed calling a function that returned an object as a string!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely because `data` is a string.  You need to parse it:

```
$.parseJSON(data).BodyDescription
```

You might also consider `getJSON` in place of your current ajax call or setting the `dataType` properly with your ajax call.

Comment: i'm returning it from c# 4.5, wouldn;t that be parsing it for me?

Comment: @Simon if you are returning with the appropriate response headers you dont need to parse json manually

Comment: apologies guys I was indeed returning a string. Time for bed I think!!

Comment: @Simon - Once you are awake again, you might want to accept an answer to boost your acceptance rating. :)  You asked 5 questions, but never accepted an answer.  To do so, just click the green outlined checkmark below the vote count on the left.

Comment: Thanks Steve, have done so now and gone back to my other questions. I'm now "in the groove" and will do so going forward!

Answer (score 2):

Change the dataType to json so that jQuery will parse it for you.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "...",
    ...
});
```

or

```
$.get(url,function(data){...},"json");
```

or

```
$.post(url,function(data){...},"json");
```